# Consume and Produce SOAP to SOAP with Apache Camel

Tags: soap, apache-camel, cxf

I wonder that consuming a web service that I am OK with Apache Camel. However, I would like to expose a SOAP based service with apache camel existing web service. It would seem a proxy service. How would I achive this? I would like you to help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This link detailed in steps:

- [Exposing SOAP service](https://www.javainuse.com/camel/Camel_Soap)
- [Consuming SOAP service](https://dzone.com/articles/exposing-and-consuming-soap)

Comment: Have already checked this site. Helped me little. I need more :) Thanks for helping btw.

Answer (score 0):

Exposing service is below given.

```
 from("cxf:bean:xxBean")
            .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
            .to("direct:XXXXX").end();
}

@Bean
public CxfEndpoint xxBean() {
    CxfEndpoint serviceEndpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
    serviceEndpoint.setServiceClass(ServiceInterface.class);
    serviceEndpoint.setDataFormat(DataFormat.POJO);
    serviceEndpoint.setAddress("URI");
    serviceEndpoint.setWsdlURL(getClass().getResource("/wsdl/xxxx.wsdl").toString());

    return serviceEndpoint;
}
```